# Using variables in terraform backend "s3"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have written below backend configuration in terraform:

```
terraform { 
  backend "s3" {
      bucket     = "${var.application_name}"
      region     = "${var.AWS_REGION}"
      key        = "tf-scripts/${var.application_name}-tfstate"
     }
 }
```

while running terraform init, I am getting below error message:

```
    terraform init
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on backend.tf line 4, in terraform:
│    4:       bucket     = "${var.application_name}"
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵

╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on backend.tf line 5, in terraform:
│    5:       region     = "${var.AWS_REGION}"
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵

╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on backend.tf line 6, in terraform:
│    6:       key        = "tf-scripts/${var.application_name}-tfstate"
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
```

Can anyone assist me on achieving the same?

Comment: You cannot use variables in that place. The config needs to be constant. *If* you want to dynamically configure the backend you need to write a wrapper script or provide a backend-config via the arguments https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#partial-configuration

Comment: terragrunt is a nice project that's essentially a wrapper to terraform configurations. Here's a link to their quick start page: https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/ They mention backends as well.

Comment: Here we are creating AWS stack using terraform where s3 is also being created, I want to store stack specific tfstate in same stack's s3 bucket. Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: You just have to change the key name. If you want the different resources in the same statefile, then they should be part of the same deployment.

Comment: We can manage to have all states in single backend s3, but want keys to be generated dynamically only, probably based on timestamp values. I tried using timestamp() but still getting an error saying function calls are not allowed here. Any suggetion?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass variables you could do something like this:

```
echo "yes" | terraform init -backend-config="${backend_env}" -backend-config="key=global/state/${backend_config}/terraform.tfstate" -backend-config="region=us-east-1" -backend-config="encrypt=true" -backend-config="kms_key_id=${kmykeyid}" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=my-platform-db-${backend_config}"
```

Now the trick here is that when you initialize it has to be done at the **command line** level.  Terraform can not do this as mentioned already by other community members, it's just the way it is.  that said you can modify the commands for initializing and pass it through as environment variables on your host or pull in variables from another source.

in this example, I declared the variables using a container through AWS Codebuild but you can use any method as long as the variable is defined prior to initialization. Let me know if you need help with this, the documentation isn't very clear and the folks on StackOverflow have been amazing at addressing this but for beginners, it's been hard to understand how this all comes together.

Comment: amazing trick!.